# How to handle App state change when our app is already in background due to prompts like SignIn with Google

Tags: react-native

Whenever prompts like SignIn with google appears on top of application, app goes in background.
Now if user manually closes app with google SignIn prompt on top, handle app state change is not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach for this case

```
   componentDidMount() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus',
            async () => {
                  this.progress()
                }
            });
    }

    async progress() {

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.focusListener.remove();
    }
```